# Iterating over ordered groups with large collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with > 10 million documents that look like:

```
{ duplicateSetId: 'xyz' published: 1676900320,  ...etc... }
```

The collection has an index for both the duplicateSetId and published fields. I am trying to iterate over all duplicate sets ordered by their minimum published value, so in other words I am trying to group by duplicateSetId and have the groups ordered by the minimum published timestamp among the documents of that group. I tried:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$duplicateSetId', minPublished: { $min: '$published' } } },
  { $sort: { minPublished: 1 } }
])
```

But this query takes ages even with indexes on the duplicateSetId and published fields, because the group operates on the entire collection. Alternatively I tried to use $limit to limit the number of documents before grouping them but it has the issue that the $limit might exclude part of the documents of a duplicate set group, which isn't an option for me. I also can't use $match to limit the number of documents to group for the same reason I can't use $limit.

Any ideas how I can speed up the above aggregation or an alternative way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Did you consider using sharding ?

Comment: How many duplicates do you have? [This optimization](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#-group-performance-optimizations) might be worth pursuing depending on the percentage of duplicates and how often you run this operation

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Create compound index on both fields if you dont have this yet:

   ```
   db.articles.createIndex({ duplicaSetId:1,published:1})
   ```

(Attention the index created in version <= mongod 4.2 may require "background" option added to avoid service unavailability )

2. Execute the query hinting mongoDB to use the index:

   ```
   db.articles.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: '$duplicateSetId', minPublished: { $min: '$published' } } },
   { $sort: { minPublished: 1 } }
   ],{hint:"duplicateSetId_1__published_1"})
   ```

where the hint need to point to the index name ...

Explained:

Hinting the mongod to use the available index is expecting to speed up the query , since indexes are smaller and most likely to be already in memory. You can confirm running the query with db.articles.explain("executionStats").aggregate(....)

Other additional options:

- add more resources(memory & cpu )
- increase mongod settings ( internal sort buffers + cacheSizeGB )
- shard the collection ( scale horizontally )
- periodically aggregate and send the output to a temporary collection
- use secondary member for the task to avoid pressure for your PRIMARY

Comment: I think hinting that index might make the operation slower with that aggregation pipeline

Comment: afcourse need to be tested since there maybe other factors , but from my experiance in similar cases is working faster ..